# PCIe M.2 SSD's NVME confusion

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, motherboard

I haven't stayed up to date on this PCIe SSD technology and I'm having a hard time deciphering if M.2 2280 has to be natively supported by the BIOS/board or if an adapter/boot software will provide adequate speeds for usage.

Specifically, I have a ASROCK EP2C602 motherboard https://www.asrockrack.com/general/productdetail.asp?Model=EP2C602#Specifications

and I'm looking at buying a 1 TB Intel 60p Series M.2 2280  NVMe 3.0 x4 3D2, QLC Internal Solid State Drive (SSD).

The system board supports PCIe 3.0 x 4, but, I can not find any information about M.2. I don't know much about that technology and was hoping someone could explain if that is an 'adapter' type tech, or if that is something that makes that SSD incompatible?

Comment: That motherboard does not support M.2 modules... Why not just use a regular SATA3 SSD drive, there is no advantage to try to install an NMVe drive in an adapter. Or if your MB has the Marvell RAID controller, install a pair of SSD's and put them in RAID0 for speed.

Comment: I have a smaller SSD Raid (100 Gb) already set up, a friend has an extra Intel 1 TB M.2 SSD I could buy for cheap, that was the entire motivation.

Comment: Well, if it's cheap enough just get a <$20 adapter and put it in and try it... a 1TB NVMe drive could have lots of potential uses in the future. It would definitely not be a able to be bootable device on it's own... You would need a bootloader on a UEFI compatible boot disk, but it would certainly work as a storage volume.

Comment: Thank you, that clears up the compatibility. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Yes;  The chipset must support booting to an M.2 NVMe drive. So since your motherboard does not have an M.2 slot you can assume it does not support it.